# Selecting ONLY the next <tr> inside dynamically generated table

Tags: jquery, css

I'm generating a table via SQL/php. It outputs one `.data-row` and one `.admin-row` in each loop. When I click the edit icon `<i class='edit-button'></i>`, I **only** need it to open the next `.admin-row` right below the  that the edit icon is in (screenshot).

Right now, I am using this jQuery code which opens **all** `.admin-row` class elements.

```
  $('.edit-button').click(function() {
    $('#dataTable').find('.admin-row').toggleClass('d-none');
  });
```

I've experimented with `.next(), .parent(), .find()` but can't get it to open only the next `.admin-row` after the edit button.

```
<?php
<table> ... / table head...

foreach($result as $row) {

echo "<tr class='data-row'>";
  echo "<td>".$date_form."</td>
  echo "<td>".$time_form."</td>
  echo "<td>".$subject_form."</td>
  echo "<td>".$public."</td>
if ($userUid == "admin") {
  echo "<td><i class='edit-button'></i></td>";
                   }
echo "</tr>";

if ($userUid == "admin") { ?>

<tr class='admin-row'>
  <form action="includes/update.inc.php" type="post">
    <td><input name="editId" type="text"></td>
    <td class='p-2' colspan="4">
      <textarea name="editContent" type="text"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td><button name="submit-edit" type="submit">EDIT</button></td>
  </form>
</tr>

 <?php }}?>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method for this like:

```
$('.edit-button').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.data-row').next('.admin-row').toggleClass('d-none');
});
```

The issue was edit button is in another row and `admin-row` is a different row.

I also found in the demo, there is no class added like `d-none`. SO, I added one like:

```
.d-none {display: none}
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
$('.edit-button').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.data-row').next('.admin-row').toggleClass('d-none');
});
```

```css
.d-none {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable" border="1">
  <tr class="data-row">
    <td>Time/date</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </td>
    <td><button class="edit-button" type="button">Edit
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="admin-row">
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td>Data3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data-row">
    <td>Time/date</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </td>
    <td><button class="edit-button" type="button">Edit
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="admin-row">
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td>Data3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's one of the approaches that I tried as well. $(this).closest('.admin-row').toggleClass('d-none'); has no effect. Maybe because the .admin-row element above and the .admin-row below have the same "distance" to the .edit-button element?

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening. Just hard code the table and rows and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: This solution works now.  My actual code seems to somehow counter this solution, I'll figure it out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this

```
$('.edit-button').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.data-row').next().toggleClass('d-none');
});
```

First select the parent .data-row of button then toggle its next elements class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This solution works in the fiddle where I tried to reproduce the problem, thank you! https://jsfiddle.net/hoini/wq439paL/13/
Now I just have to figure out why it doesn't work in my dynamically generated table:)

Comment: In that case just check in inspector tools that on button click your class is getting toggled or not and if it is then just add relative css rules to that class to make div toggle, also you can specify the .next(".admin-row") to narrow the elements.

Comment: It was a form element around the <tr> that prevented the <tr> toggle. Thanks a lot for your help, Gagandeep